# Ignore incoming MIDI from my own App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, midi

I'm using the PGMidi wrapper and have created the MIDI source for my test app with the code below.

```
s = MIDISourceCreate(client, (CFStringRef)@"MIDItest", &virtualSource);
```

Other MIDI aps detect my app as "MIDItest" just fine.  I'm trying to retrieve my source name "MIDItest" within my app using the code below but I only receive "session 1"

```
for (PGMidiSource *source in midi.sources)
{
    NSLog(source.name);
    source.delegate = self;
}
```

My app needs to send and receive MIDI and I need to detect if the connection source is my own app so that I don't connect to it.  What is the best way to do this and why is the source name MIDItest not returned in my own app but detected in other MIDI aps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you're creating a source using `MIDISourceCreate` then it's not included in `midi.sources` because that is part of the `PGMidi` library which will create it's own source for your app. What are you doing with your source `s` after you create it?

Are you sure that other MIDI apps can't see your app as two sources; the one that you are creating as `"MIDItest"` and the one that `PGMidi` creates?